# Can I make my iMac boot from an OS on an external drive in safe mode?

Tags: macos, boot, external-hard-drive, safe-mode

I've searched all over the internet but I could not find a concrete answer to this question: I have an iMac that works fine and an external hard drive with OSX on it that I can boot too, but how can I boot to that drive in safe mode? Thanks!

Comment: Try if this works: If your mac is on, Shut Down. After the mac powers off, wait 10 seconds.  Plugin the external hdd. Press the power button and immediately hold the Option (⌥) key till the startup manager appears. Select your external hdd as the startup disk with your arrow keys. Press the SHIFT key and press ENTER key. Do not release the SHIFT key till the Apple logo and progress indicator appears. Let us know if it works. (Note: This is only for macOS Mojave and above).

Comment: @sfxedit unfortunately I am on High sierra, but I found a different way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after your Mac is switched on:

First you select to boot from external drive by holding Option key and waiting for the list of disk choices.

Immediately after you select the external disk among boot options, you press and hold shift for safe boot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I figured it out just before you posted it, but I'll accept yours